# Apex Test Class - Simple Lead Insert How Do I Test?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

Trying to teach myself Salesforce Development.

I created a Lightning Component for a Communities page to create a Lead. The component works fine, simply calls the Apex class to insert the Lead.

However, I can't figure out how to write the test class required before this can be passed to production.

Here is the Apex Class to create the Lead:

```
public class LightningLeadCreatecls {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void createLead(Lead leadObj){
        insert leadObj; 
    }
}
```

I have written Apex Test Classes for Apex Classes that simply pull data with SELECT, but can't figure out how to create this test class. It is at 0/2.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE - this is a good project for a first unit test because its functionality is straightforward and easy to validate. Have you done the Trailhead module on [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing)? Another good resource often recommended here is [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests).

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at some of the other questions on unit testing here or google "unit testing" (and as you gain more experience with unit testing), you'll see a couple of common themes.

- You only gain coverage for code that is executed as part of a unit test method
- Code coverage is the best metric that Salesforce has available for determining whether or not to allow your code to be deployed
- The real value (to us, as developers) from unit tests isn't from the coverage, but rather from *the assertions*
- Don't break the data isolation of unit tests if you can avoid it (and we can avoid this in >= 99.9% of cases). Create all the data you need for your test *inside of the test method* (or, ideally, in a non-test method annotated with `@testSetup`)

Your first attempt is better than most, because it contains an assertion and you're creating your own test data.

Where your attempt falls flat is that *it doesn't call the method in the class that you're trying to test*.

Let's take a simple example:

```java
public class SimpleClass{
    public Integer addInts(Integer arg1, Integer arg2){
        return arg1 + arg2;
    }
}
```

A test class for `SimpleClass` might look like this:

```java
@isTest
private class SimpleClassTest{
    @isTest
    static void testSimpleAddition(){
        // Phase 1 of unit testing: Set up your test environment
        Integer int1 = 2;
        Integer int2 = 2;

        SimpleClass testInstance = new SimpleClass();

        // Phase 2 of unit testing: Execute the test
        // Test.start/stopTest aren't strictly necessary, especially with such a simple
        //   class, but it is good practice.
        Test.startTest();
        Integer result = testInstance.addInts(int1, int2);
        Test.stopTest();

        // Phase 3 of unit testing: Gather results, and make assertions
        // Capturing and storing the result of calling addInts technically falls into
        //   this phase, but we kinda need to store the return value of a method
        //   right away.

        // If possible, it's generally better to compute your expected values rather than
        //   just hard-coding 2 + 2 = 4, so my expected value should be 4.
        // The idea is that expectedResult = 4 uses a "magic number".
        // "Magic" in the sense of "we don't know why we're using _this_ particular
        //   value, _it just works_"
        // Again, not so much of an issue here, but it becomes more of an issue the
        //   more complex your code/test becomes.
        Integer expectedResult = int1 + int2;

        // assertEquals and assertNotEquals have a 2-parameter version, and a 3-parameter
        //   version.
        // The third parameter allows you to add a custom message to the result if
        //   the assertion fails, which can make it a lot easier to figure out precisely
        //   what is failing.
        // "expected: 4, actual: fish :addInts method produced an incorrect result"
        //   is a _lot_ more helpful than "expected: 4, actual: fish"
        System.assertEquals(expectedResult, result, 'addInts method produced an incorrect result');
    }
}
```

The main takeaway for you here is that *the purpose of the test method is to have it call the thing that you want to test*. We can assume that Salesforce does the basic things correctly, so `System.assertEquals(4, 2 + 2, 'incorrect addition');` isn't helpful. What we're trying to test is that *our work* does what we think it should be doing.

Instead of inserting your `Lead` directly in the test method, you want to make sure your `createLead(Lead)` method actually does what it says on the tin (i.e. that it inserts your lead).

Questions of the form "how do I test X?" where "X" is something special like a webservice or an `@auraenabled` annotated method generally come down to the fact that, from a testing perspective, there's very little difference between a "normal" method and one of these "special" methods. Just make an instance of the class, and call the method.

In your particular case, since you have a *static* method you're trying to test. You'll just invoke the method directly like `LightningCreateLeads.createLead(myLead);`

I'd also consider re-writing your assertion so that it checks that, when you query all of the Leads available in your test method, you have one more `Lead` after running the method you're testing compared to the number of `Leads` you had before running the method you're testing.

A last bit of parting advice:

Instead of focusing on code coverage, try to focus on the different situations you can think up that your code may need to handle. "Negative" cases (where some part of your test environment is not 100% perfect) are important to test as well. What would happen if you passed in `null` to your method? What would happen if you passed a Lead in that was already inserted?

You can have more than one test method in a test class. My rule of thumb is one scenario = one test method. Covering a sufficient number of possible scenarios will naturally lead to high coverage, and also help ensure that your code is *robust* (or, at the very least, that you know how your code behaves in a variety of situations).